# Using the leftover width after a relative container.

Tags: html, css

In my page I have a relative container which is used to hold an image and some "floating" information ontop of the image. This is being used in a hybrid mobile application. I need to make use of the remaining space at the bottom of the page.

Here's an example of how my page setup looks (CSS):

```
// Contains an image scaling to device width.
.rel-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

// Used to overlay the image with a 20% dark overlay.
.abs-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.20;
    background: black;
}

// Contains some images based on special parameters.
.abs-container {
    position: absolute;
    ...
}

// Contains parameter based text.
.abs-text {
   position: absolute;
   ...
}

// Should use 40% of remaining space, but doesn't?
.norm-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="rel-container">
        <image src="http://placehold.it/512" width="100%">
        <div class="abs-overlay"></div>
        <div class="abs-text">...</div>
        <div class="abs-container">...</div>
    </div>

    <div class="norm-container">
        ...
    </div>
</body>
```

I've tried messing around with various positioning types to get this to work properly, but I just can't figure out how to use the remaining space at the bottom of the page in a container. I could always just continue the layout inside of the `<div class="rel-container">` but the issue is the overlay used for the image.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get what you're trying to achieve. So basically you want to put content inside the `norm-container` div?

Comment: @kevinMario - I would like the `norm-container` div to use the remaining space left over at the bottom of the page that the `rel-container` div is not using. This value is different based on device resolution.

Comment: I think we need a demo.

Comment: Code posted serves as a `non-functional` example. I'm trying to make `norm-container` fill the remaining height of the screen. However every question about this, or "fix" using overlays or nested containers is not working.